# OpenGL perspective and lighting problem

Tags: iphone, c++, c, opengl-es

I have a sample 3d scene rendered using OpenGL ES 1.1.
Here is what I get when I have identity projection matrix (I'm also using normal and specular maps):

[image]

So everything looks OK.

But if I set perspective using `glFrustum` I get this:

[image]

So it seems that normals are being inverted and if I try to multiply them by -1 I get this:

[image]

It has an effect like the light was from the opposite side.

I should also mention that when using identity projection matrix I have to set

`glCullFace(GL_FRONT);`

(I think this is because normalized device coords are left handed).

I'll be happy to hear any suggestions about how to fix this issue.

Edit.
here is the projection setup:

```
float right = 0.03;
float top = 0.045;
float near = 0.1;
float far = 100.0;

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustumf(-right, right, -top, top, near, far);
```

Comment: Re-export your normals facing the right direction?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change `glCullFace(GL_FRONT)`. Maybe your projection matrix is inverting the faces? Show us your `glFrustum` call. Is this the ony thing you are changing?

Comment: @Banthar - I'm using glCullFace(GL_FRONT) for the identity projection and not for perspective. See my edits.

Comment: "So it seems that normals are being inverted" That's an odd conclusion to make. It seems to me that the screenshot with the perspective projection makes the most sense. But you neglected to tell us what direction the light was coming from, so it's kinda hard to be certain.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The light is coming directly from above (along (0,-1,0)). In the end the model must look like on the first screenshot (cause it looks like this in Maya and 3Ds Max). I should also note, that there may be a problem with texture blending, cause I'm rendering the model in 3 passes (diffuse->normal->specular).

Answer (score 0):

Your second screenshot looks okay, I don't see where your problem is. please highlight in the second picture, what you think doesn't look right.

Remember that in the projection matrix there should only be the projection, and kind of camera placement at all. The "camera placement" belongs into the modelview.

Comment: Unfortunately the second screen looks not like it should. The model has squama and it is rendered with the help of normal map. The first screen - that is how it should look like. And also if you didn't notice (it's better visible on an animated model) that the model is not smoothly shaded on the second screen (unlike the first one).

Comment: I don't think your problems are the problem. I think the problem is somewhere in your fragment shader and if I have to make a guess you're probably messed up the tangent space → eye space transformation.

Comment: I'm using the OpenGL 1.1, so I don't have any shaders.

Comment: So how did you do the normal mapping then? I only know about one way to do normal mapping without the aid of shaders, which involves some per normal tangent space transformation. Also this explains why your lighting may not look right: If your normal map only modules the light term, you will still have per vertex lighting, which explains the smoothness problem you mention.